# How to send email more than one "cc Recipients" using rest api v1.0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, microsoft-graph-api, servicenow

I am working with Microsoft graph api. Just need to know that how i can send email more than one recipient using below code.
I am trying with attached code but giving the below error in response body.

```
test 1 {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Property ccRecipients in payload has a value that does not match schema.","innerError":{"date":"2023-09-05T19:14:25","request-id":"4786cf69-9ef9-4d9b-83c4-8db8a1005291","client-request-id":"4786cf69-9ef9-4d9b-83c4-8db8a1005291"}}}
```

```
var ccaddresses = current.getValue('copied').split(',');
var ccRe = [];

for (i = 0; i < ccaddresses.length; i++) {
    ccRe.push({
        "emailAddress": {
            "addresss": ccaddresses[i]+''
        }
    });
}



// Set the request body
var requestBody = {

    "message": {
        "subject": current.getValue('subject'),
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": current.getValue('body')
        },
        "toRecipients": [{
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": current.getValue('direct')
            }
        }],
        "ccRecipients": JSON.stringify(ccRe)
    },
    "saveToSentItems": "true"
};
```

I am getting email id in cc like below.

```
"toRecipients":[{"emailAddress":{"address":"brijmohan.kushwaha@test.co.in"}}],"ccRecipients":"[{\"emailAddress\":{\"addresss\":\"vipul.kush@test.com\"}},{\"emailAddress\":{\"addresss\":\" deepak.kushwaha@test.com\"}}]"},"saveToSentItems":"true"}
```

Comment: `ccRecipients` should probably be set to `ccRe` rather than `JSON.stringify(ccRe)`.

Comment: You didn't convert the `toRecipients`  array to JSON, why do you think you need to do that with `ccRecipients`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey After setting ccRe now I am getting below error. test 1 {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"The property 'addresss' does not exist on type 'microsoft.graph.emailAddress'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type."}} . Also getting cc like below format - "toRecipients":[{"emailAddress":{"address":"brijmohan.kushwaha@test.co.in"}}],"ccRecipients":[{"emailAddress":{"addresss":"vipul.kush@test.com"}},{"emailAddress":{"addresss":" deepak.kushwaha@test.co.in"}}]},"saveToSentItems":"true"}

Comment: I have no idea. I just saw that `JSON.stringify()` and figured that was it. The details of the various formats the Graph API uses should be available online somewhere...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the property name eg

```
"addresss": ccaddresses[i]+''
```

should be

```
"address": ccaddresses[i]+''
```

eg one too many s, that seems to be what the error is complaining about the rest looks okay.

Comment: Thanks @GlenScales, Its worked. Can you please let me know how I can handle null value in cc because it is not working if we don't have any value in cc?

Comment: Most likely to do with how your handling the null values eg it should just be "ccRecipients": [] but for instance if your pushing an empty string into the array my guess is your sending something like [""] (or if you send null as the value) this wouldn't be valid. The error that Graph returns should give you a hint as to what is going wrong.